# Convert IsolatedStorageFileStream to b64 string in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have mp4 files in Isolated Storage and I am reading this by using `IsolatedStorageFileStream`. After read the file I need to convert it into `b64` string.

So I am not getting proper code for this. If anyone knows then please help me.

Answer (score 1):

//Convert the IsolatedStorageFileStream to Base64 String and take the length of the file.

```
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(isoVideoFile);
            long length = reader.BaseStream.Length;
            int rr = Convert.ToInt32(length);
            byte[] chunk = reader.ReadBytes(rr);//reading the bytes 
            string temp_inBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(chunk);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes[])`